# Node app crashes on Heroku (Express-cors related); app runs fine locally

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have deployed my first Node app to Heroku. It runs fine with `foreman start` but crashes on Heroku.

The procfile is there and valid: `foreman check` `valid procfile detected (web)` content `web: node app.js`

According to the `heroku logs` there is a problem with the Express-cors module.

```
2015-05-25T09:29:32.530535+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2015-05-25T09:29:33.912050+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
2015-05-25T09:29:33.912079+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
2015-05-25T09:29:34.264204+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:338
2015-05-25T09:29:34.264210+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2015-05-25T09:29:34.264212+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2015-05-25T09:29:34.264214+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'express-cors'
2015-05-25T09:29:34.264216+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
2015-05-25T09:29:34.264217+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
2015-05-25T09:29:34.264218+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
2015-05-25T09:29:34.264220+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:384:17)
2015-05-25T09:29:34.264222+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:2:12)
2015-05-25T09:29:34.264223+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
2015-05-25T09:29:34.264224+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
2015-05-25T09:29:34.264226+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
2015-05-25T09:29:34.264228+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
2015-05-25T09:29:34.264229+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
2015-05-25T09:29:35.085157+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-05-25T09:29:35.086239+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-05-25T09:29:35.069352+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-05-25T09:29:37.209488+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2015-05-25T09:29:38.965715+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
2015-05-25T09:29:38.965737+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
2015-05-25T09:29:39.288408+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:338
2015-05-25T09:29:39.288412+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2015-05-25T09:29:39.288416+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2015-05-25T09:29:39.288418+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'express-cors'
2015-05-25T09:29:39.288421+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
2015-05-25T09:29:39.288420+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
2015-05-25T09:29:39.288422+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
2015-05-25T09:29:39.288425+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:2:12)
2015-05-25T09:29:39.288424+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:384:17)
2015-05-25T09:29:39.288426+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
2015-05-25T09:29:39.288428+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
2015-05-25T09:29:39.288429+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
2015-05-25T09:29:39.288432+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
2015-05-25T09:29:39.288431+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    2015-05-25T09:29:39.982048+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2015-05-25T09:29:39.971753+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-05-25T09:29:41.341772+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by email@gmail.com
2015-05-25T09:29:48.007388+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=immense-spire-2945.herokuapp.com request_id=576a02a2-447d-48aa-ab21-63aa576027c1 fwd="213.113.58.143" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-05-25T09:29:49.472658+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=immense-spire-2945.herokuapp.com request_id=c18744e7-f029-4035-a0ef-cdf6b0d25305 fwd="213.113.58.143" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-05-25T09:29:52.332338+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=immense-spire-2945.herokuapp.com request_id=8f5750d3-bb54-43d2-a86d-c1176af43277 fwd="213.113.58.143" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-05-25T09:29:56.998627+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=immense-spire-2945.herokuapp.com request_id=296fa816-f2f3-458f-8c85-95bc7a53057b fwd="213.113.58.143" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-05-25T09:33:19.006725+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=immense-spire-2945.herokuapp.com request_id=f99e20dd-f73a-4ccd-b746-0bd8ec021d27 fwd="213.113.58.143" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-05-25T09:33:21.467535+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=immense-spire-2945.herokuapp.com request_id=2937160d-6635-4d73-8d25-a3ee0c73e472 fwd="213.113.58.143" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

How do I fix this?

Edit: Heroku support was very helpful. 
If you have this issue, firstly you should check that your package.json file contains all of the needed dependencies.

Secondly, you should add the following to your app.js file:

```
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Otherwise the app will be attempting `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` instead.